# Hide Div and Scroll to anchor using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have links that show/hide a div based on click and this seems to work fine. I am trying to make it work such that, once a link is clicked, a div is hidden, the hidden div is then shown and depending on which link is clicked, it then scrolls to the associated anchor point. In the example below, it want it to scroll to #cf when then CF link is clicked. How do I go about achieving this?

[Fiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/zp5jre83/)

```
$('.o-c').click(function() {
 $('.main-home').hide("slide", {
 direction: "right"
 }, 1000);
 $('.section-pages').show("slide", {
 direction: "right"
 }, 1000);

 });

$('.c-f').click(function() {
$('.main-home').hide("slide", {
direction: "right"
}, 1000);
$('.section-pages').show("slide", {
direction: "right"
}, 1000);

});

$('.back').click(function() {
$('.section-pages').hide("slide", {
direction: "right"
}, 1000);
$('.main-home').show("slide", {
direction: "right"
}, 1000);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a callback on show complete.

Try this:

```
$('.c-f').click(function () {
    $('.main-home').hide("slide", {direction: "right"}, 1000);
    $('.section-pages').show("slide", {direction: "right"}, 1000, function() {
        $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
            scrollTop: $("#cf").offset().top
        }, 2000);      
      });               
  });
```

Comment: Thank you. Rather than Scroll would it be able to just go to that div, without scrolling?

Comment: @user38208 Sure you can. Just set scrollTop instead of animation. Check this code:

`$('.c-f').click(function () {
   $('.main-home').hide("slide", {direction: "right"}, 1000);
   $('.section-pages').show("slide", {direction: "right"}, 1000, function() {
      $([document.documentElement, document.body]).scrollTop($("#cf").offset().top)
      });   
  }); `